# Speeding up Phylogenetic Tree Traversal in R

Tags: r, performance, optimization, parallel-processing, tree

I have the following code that is supposed to take a phylogenetic tree (in phylo4 format) and for every internal node return the sum of the two children's branch length (the trees are binary). I am not sure why but this is terribly slow compared to other functions I have written on trees of similar size (~45,000 leaves).

```
require(phylobase)
require(parallel)

# df.ilr is the ILR transformed data
# tr is the corresponding tree
calculate.blw <- function(tr, n_cores=1){
  # Note that some of the terminal branches of the tree have zero length. 
  # In these cases  I will replace those zero values with 
  # the minimum branch length (greater than 0) found in the tree.
  min.nonzero <- min(edgeLength(tr)[edgeLength(tr)>0 & !is.na(edgeLength(tr))])
  edgeLength(tr)[edgeLength(tr) == 0 & !is.na(edgeLength(tr))] <- min.nonzero

  coords.names <- nodeLabels(tr)
  #blw <- rep(NA, length(coords.names)) # [b]ranch-[l]ength [w]eights
  fxn <- function(x){
    childs <- names(descendants(tr, x, type='children'))
    return(sum(edgeLength(tr, childs)))
  }

  cl <- makeCluster(n_cores, 'FORK')
  blw <- parSapply(cl, coords.names, fxn)
  stopCluster(cl)
  names(blw) <- coords.names

  return(blw)
}
```

Suggestions on memory efficiency would also be welcome!